# Upload Mp3/Database files from PEN DRIVE to SD CARD problem with speed

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplab-harmony

I am using a **PIC32MZ2048EFH144** micro controller in my project with Microchip harmony. I am using USB for the pen-drive and SPI protocol for the SD card. Everything was working properly when I uploaded the pen-drive's data to SD card. When I upload above 2000 mp3 files, though, it takes 20 to 25 minutes. How can I boost transfer speed and upload all the files in 5 to 10 minutes? The SPI is running at **40MHZ** and the **USB at full speed**.

**If the file size is under 10kb then 500 files are uploaded in less then 2 minutes**. Can anyone please give me suggestions on how I can boost transfer speed.

Comment: Sorry , I am using                            #define DRV_SPI_BAUD_RATE_IDX0    40000000  , 40MHZ freq for SPI

Comment: SD cards spec allows up to 25 MHz for SPI, but USB *full speed* is 12 MHz.

Comment: Both of SPI and USB handled by Micro controller , M'CU read data from Pen Drive and write to SD CARD using SPI. my USB running at 12 Mhz but i don't know why Transfer Speed is very slow. Do you have any suggestions, how can i improve transfer speed?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many variable involved that you have not given sufficient information for outsiders to give complete and/or valid tips.

Lets start with some simple math considering the maximum throughput of USB full (around 1 MB/s) and an average MP3 file size of 3.5 MB :

```
2000 files * 3.5 MB/file / 1 MB/s = 7000 s = 117 min
```

With 10 kb:

```
2000 files * 0.01 MB/file / 1 MB/s = 20 s
```

So already, depending on the actual use case, you may or may not be USB limited and we cant tell you which without more data. Another issue is that saturating the USB and doing other meaningful tasks such as managing a file system and sending the data back out the SPI may not be possible with simple purely procedural MCU code if your not running at maximum clock speed. You will likely need to use DMA transfers to keep your buffers flowing while you manage the file system on the CPU. If your software is not a bottleneck, your MCU does support USB High speed which definitely could not saturate before software or the SPI does.